# How to hide oracle BI publisher 11g running report URL in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, bi-publisher, oracle-apex-5.1

I am working on reporting Tool Called Oracle BI Publisher 11g . I want to use webservices of BI publisher instead of using BI publisher Desktop ... I created a parameterized report in BI Publisher and call URL in oracle apex 5.1 and i passed parameter through it when i run the report. this report requesting me about username and Password then pass BI publisher web username and password through URL then it looks Like::

http://localhost:9704/xmlpserver/ACH.xdo?_id=username&_pass=password&_xpf=&_xpt=1&_xdo=%2FACH.xdo&_xmode=&_paramsP_AC=&_paramsP_UC=&_xt…

But This is Not Secure I want to make it secure Something Like

http://localhost:9704/xmlpserver/ACH.xdo

Can anyone Help me to make this Secure.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use BI Publisher (so why am I writing this, eh?). I was hoping that it works like Oracle Reports use to, i.e. you create reports' entries in CGICMD.DAT file on IAS (application server) that contain credentials, report name and list of parameters. When calling a report, URL won't display that information.

BI Publisher, however, doesn't have that option - at least, I didn't manage to find any. [Accessing Reports via a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80149_01/bip/BIPRD/GUID-F788B306-99F6-432E-BCD5-F45046D31684.htm#BIPRD3321) says that - regarding security considerations - you should configure both applications (your Apex app. and BI Publisher) as partner applications in an SSO server; doing so, BI Publisher won't ask user to log in and will display the report.

Now, as I don't know much about SSO I can't guide you through that process, but I hope that the fact that both Apex and BI Publisher are Oracle products makes that task feasible.